# iOS: CocoaLumberjack(version 3.5.1) is alway creating new file on app launch

Tags: ios, swift, cocoalumberjack

I am using cocoa `lumberjack` to store my app logs. I want to roll the log file based on size only (if it reaches `1MB`).

Below code i am using for configuration.

```
    let fileLogger: DDFileLogger = DDFileLogger()   
     fileLogger.rollingFrequency = -1
    fileLogger.maximumFileSize = 1024 * 1024
    fileLogger.logFileManager.maximumNumberOfLogFiles = 7
    DDLog.add(fileLogger
```

But i am facing one problem, it is creating new file on every time app launch instead of creating after reaching 1MB.

As of my analysis in `DDFileLogger.m` file under  `- (NSFileHandle *)lt_currentLogFileHandle` method, `_currentLogFileHandle` property is alway nil on app launch.

is anything i am missing here. Please suggest me

I am using cocoaLumberjack 3.5.1 version.
app supports from iOS 10
Xcode version 10.1

Comment: I think you need to use the `initWithLogFileManager:` version to create the `DDFileLogger` instance with your own version of the file manager.  See [this page](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/blob/master/Documentation/LogFileManagement.md).  Alternatively write your own logger class which shouldn't take more than an hour.  I've never been satisfied with anyone elses logging code.

Comment: @trojanfoe. I did not get you. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You have to create your own log file manager class in order to manage log file creation I believe.  See the page I linked.

Comment: what if you set maximumNumberOfLogFiles to 1 ?

Comment: this maybe helpful too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991208/cocoalumberjack-log-to-one-file

Comment: @Mosbah if i set maximumNumberOfLogFiles to 1 on app launch it is deleting old file and creating new file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS CocoaLumberjack: New log file is creating on every time app launch, if backgroundModes enabled and app running in simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54919967/ios-cocoalumberjack-new-log-file-is-creating-on-every-time-app-launch-if-backg)

Comment: This was bug with CocoaLumberjack library. They released new version with fix.