# iOS CocoaLumberjack: New log file is creating on every time app launch, if backgroundModes enabled and app running in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, cocoalumberjack, ddfilelogger

I have configured library like below

```
    let fileLogger: DDFileLogger = DDFileLogger() 
    fileLogger.rollingFrequency = -1
    fileLogger.maximumFileSize = 1024 * 1024
    fileLogger.logFileManager.maximumNumberOfLogFiles = 7
    DDLog.add(fileLogger)
```

File has to roll only if it reaches `1MB` size. Recently i observed one thing, if app running in simulator with background mode enabled. New log file is creating on every time app launch irrespective of file size. Is this known thing?. Because `NSFileProtectionType` is nil inside `doesAppRunInBackground()` condition in `DDFileLogger.m` class. But it is working fine in device

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
fileLogger.logFileManager.maximumNumberOfLogFiles = 1;
```

If that does not work then try setting `NSFileProtectionType` to either true or 1 inside `doesAppRunInBackground()` function inside the DDFileLogger.m class.

Comment: setting maximumNumberOfLogFiles = 1 simply delete old file and create new one on every launch. How to set NSFileProtectionType to true. You mean hardcode value?

Comment: Yes hardcore value